# What is the outer automorphism group of the Pauli group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Let $P_n$ be the [Pauli group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_group) on n qubits.
The order of the group is $|P_n| = 2^{2n+2}$. I beleive the outer automorphism group is closely related to the symplectic group $Sp(2n,2)$ but I don't know the exact relation. Direct calculations for small n seem to show that $|Out(P_n)| = 2 |Sp(2n,2)|$. Does anyone know of how this can shown in general or a reference on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some work was done a while ago by Michael Planat on the outer automorphism groups of the Pauli group [1]. He has some other resources that may be good to look at as well [2], and you could also look on Google Scholar for other papers / collaborators to start a more thorough search.

### Sources

1. Planat, Michel, and Maurice Kibler. "Unitary reflection groups for quantum fault tolerance." Journal of computational and theoretical nanoscience 7.9 (2010): 1759-1770. [Link here](https://www.arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3650.pdf)
2. “Reflection Groups for Quantum Computing” slide deck, Michael Planat. [Link here](https://www.geometrie.tuwien.ac.at/zif-cg09/pdf/lecture_planat3.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I have since found this paper : AUTOMORPHISMS OF EXTRA SPECIAL GROUPS AND NONVANISHING DEGREE 2 COHOMOLOGY, ROBERT L. GRIESS, JR., PACIFIC JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS Vol. 48, No. 2, 1973. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-48/issue-2/Automorphisms-of-extra-special-groups-and-nonvanishing-degree-2-cohomology/pjm/1102945424.pdf. The factor of 2 corresponds to an automorphism that acts on the center alone ("complex conjugation"); the automorphisms that fix the center correspond to $Sp(2n,2)$.